# HTML button design with gradient in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have below HTML button style. it works fine in Fire fox but in IE it does not render properly. I am using IE7. but it should work in all IE versions above 7.

In FF:

[image]

But in IE its look is different:

[image]

Below is my CSS style:

```
button.skip {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #8C9CBF;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #8C9CBF 0%, #546A9E 50%, #36518F 50%, #3D5691 100%);
    border-color: #172D6E #172D6E #0E1D45;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #B1B9CB inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: bold 16px/1 "helvetica neue",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    padding: 7px 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #000F4D;
    width: 150px;

}
```

How can i display the button in IE similar to FF ? Thanks!

Comment: you should use pie.htc for ie old versions

Comment: If you use only `-moz`-prefixed CSS properties it's not going to work anywhere else except Firefox.

Comment: If you are using IE8 you have to use a own prefix.. -moz is only for mozilla..

Comment: The easiest way would be what people did before css gradients were introduced, just use an image.

Comment: http://responsivewebinc.com/bootstrap-tutorial/css3-gradient-on-bootstrap/

Comment: Just a general hint: **NEVER** write in all browsers. You cannot support them all. Especially let's say Internet Explorer 4.0 or some newer 6.0 that is such a pain! Better write in all modern browsers. That is also very *very* important if you talk with your customers.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;

background: #8c9cbf; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%, #546a9e 50%, #36518f 50%, #3d5691 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#8c9cbf), color-stop(50%,#546a9e), color-stop(50%,#36518f), color-stop(100%,#3d5691)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 50%,#3d5691 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 50%,#3d5691 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 50%,#3d5691 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 50%,#3d5691 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8c9cbf', endColorstr='#3d5691',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS that you have to add for your button to work in IE

```
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dcdedb 0%, #c9cbc8 100%);
        /* IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dcdedb', endColorstr='#c9cbc8', GradientType=0);
        /* IE6-9 */
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xRcXL/988/)

EDIT: [NEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EPCUd/)

In case of IE9 and below you will not be able to use CSS3 gradients because **IE9,IE8,IE7 does not support CSS3 gradients**. An alternative is to create *PNG* buttons and assign the *background image* of the button to the *PNG*.

An alternative would be to use **SVG**. However i would not recommend that because using **SVG** just for the sake of creating one *fancy button* for **IE7** does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. still it is not rendering. in the screen shot in which i added as some horizontal thick line inside the button but the same is missing in IE

Comment: @user1016403, Check the new DEMO. worked for me in all browsers

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Still in IE the horizontal line inside button is not coming...

Comment: @user1016403, you will not be able to see the line in case of IE9 and below.

Answer (score 1):

ie7 does not support css3 gradient property you should use pie.htc for ie8,ie7

here is the link for its page

http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try IE specific CSS

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8C9CBF 0%, #546A9E 50%, #36518F 50%, #3D5691 100%); // IE 10
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#546A9E', endColorstr='#3D5691',GradientType=0 ); // IE 6-9
```

Tinker around with the values as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Colorzilla Gradient Generator: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

and CSS3Pie: http://css3pie.com

Try this:

```
background: #8c9cbf; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzhjOWNiZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzU0NmE5ZSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUxJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzM2NTE4ZiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMzZDU2OTEiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%, #546a9e 50%, #36518f 51%, #3d5691 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#8c9cbf), color-stop(50%,#546a9e), color-stop(51%,#36518f), color-stop(100%,#3d5691)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 51%,#3d5691 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 51%,#3d5691 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 51%,#3d5691 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8c9cbf 0%,#546a9e 50%,#36518f 51%,#3d5691 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8c9cbf', endColorstr='#3d5691',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

and for Support in IE9:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

check this CSS3 Gradient Generator

http://gradients.glrzad.com/

and this

https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cssmatic.com%2Fgradient-generator&ei=90T2Ubz9FMSBtAa9v4CQDQ&usg=AFQjCNGsHA3AwD64r0PasZYe6JilW76msA&sig2=J-8dt2Oe-wTCailSEGucZA

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/

http://css3gen.com/gradient-generator/